# Parse List to a String in Open CSV

Tags: java, spring-boot, opencsv

I am using Spring-Boot and OpenCsv to convert `MyEntity` to a csv and return it as a response. The String fields are parsed as expected. One of the fields of MyEntity (`myList`) is a list of `MyClass` and i would Like to parse this field to a json string. How do I tell Open CSV to do the parsing instead of taking the toString() of the list? Is there any field annotation that I can add to field and define the mapping there?

```
public class MyEntity {
    
      public String myName;
      
      public List<MyClass> myList
    
}



StatefulBeanToCsv<MyClass> bean = new StatefulBeanToCsvBuilder<>(writer)
          .withQuotechar(CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER)
          .withSeparator(',')
          .build();
      bean.write(myEntities)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(myList);
```

dependency gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.5'
}
```

or maven

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
      <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
      <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: Thanks @Vojin , actually I know how to parse object to json , my question was how to tell OpenCsv to use this parsing instead of toString of the List?

Comment: parse whole MyEntity object to json and pass json version of object